# Issue with dojo dijit.form.ValidationTextBox

Tags: javascript, dojo

The following XHTML code is not working:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/dojotoolkit/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/dojotoolkit/dojo/resources/dojo.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/dojotoolkit/dojo/dojo.js" djConfig="parseOnLoad: true" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        dojo.require("dijit.form.ValidationTextBox");
        dojo.require("dojo.parser");
    </script>
</head>

<body class="nihilo">
    <input type="text" dojoType="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox" size="30" />
</body>

</html>
```

In Firebug I get the following error message:

> [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004003
>   (NS_ERROR_INVALID_POINTER) [nsIDOMNSHTMLElement.innerHTML]"  nsresult:
>   "0x80004003 (NS_ERROR_INVALID_POINTER)"  location: "JS frame ::
>   http://localhost:21000/dojotoolkit/dojo/dojo.js :: anonymous :: line
>   319"  data: no] http://localhost:21000/dojotoolkit/dojo/dojo.js Line
>   319

Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The problem seams to be the ending of the file...

- If I name the file [test2.html](http://www.tasix.ch/Greter/test2.html) everything works.
- If I name the file [test2.xhtml](http://www.tasix.ch/Greter/test2.xhtml) I get the error message.

The diverence between the two seams to be the Content-Type in the response header from apache.

- For .html it is Content-Type    text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
- For .xhtml it is Content-Type   application/xhtml+xml

Answer (score 1):

Where you import dojo.js:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/dojotoolkit/dojo/dojo.js" djConfig="parseOnLoad: true"/>
```

It should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/dojotoolkit/dojo/dojo.js" djConfig="parseOnLoad:true"></script>
```

Have fun with dojo, it's can do some cool stuff.

Brian Gianforcaro

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that innerHTML is an unofficial property that is not part of the W3C specifications, and thus may or may not work depending upon the browser, especially when the page is being rendered as a XHTML file rather than a HTML file. See [here](http://domscripting.com/blog/display/35) and [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/bugreports/archives/2004/11/innerhtml_in_xh.html).

Answer (score 0):

Well, what is dojo.js doing at line 319?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your pointing to the right path in the script tags?

I put it up on the web, check it out.

The left is Dojo parsed input, the right is an regular old input. 
[Link](http://tncrocks.com/test/stackoverflow/)

I'm on OS X, using firefox 3.0.1 I get no errors under firebug.

Answer (score 0):

There are some similar tickets on the dojo trac page:

http://trac.dojotoolkit.org/search?q=xhtml+ns_error&noquickjump=1&ticket=on

Probably you are facing a bug and you will need to fill a new ticket.